# Ignore the text enclosed in double quotes

Tags: php, google-translate

I am using the following code to translate English text into French using Google Translate. But I want to ignore the text enclosed in double quotes e.g. "Hello", Comment ca va? NOT as "Bonjour!", Comment ca va? Please help!

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//require 'vendor/google/cloud-translate/src/V2/TranslateClient.php';
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V2\TranslateClient;

$translate = new TranslateClient([
'key' => 'xyzGoogleTranlateApiKey'
]);

$strText = $_POST['strText'];
$arrLanguages = array(
array("Language"=>"French", "Code"=>"fr"),
);

        
        
foreach($arrLanguages as $lang)
{
$strLangTitle = $lang['Language'];
$strLangCode = $lang['Code'];

$result = $translate->translate($strText, [
'target' => $strLangCode
]);
?>
<div class="lang <?php echo $strLangCode;?>">
<h2><?php echo $strLangTitle;?></h2>
<p><?php echo $result['text'];?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to just strip quotes? Or do you want to remove, then add them back after translation? Guess not clear on how it interferes with the translation process.